# Prove that $X|X + Y$ is a Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $λ$ and $Y$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $μ$.
$X, Y$ are assumed to be independent.

Prove that $X|X + Y$ is a Binomial random variable with the success probability $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/936828/

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-distributions] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Poisson random variables and Binomial Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936828/poisson-random-variables-and-binomial-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

A Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda$ is the number of events occuring in one time unit in a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Whenever the $X+Y$ events occurred, since with probability $1$ they occurred at different times, we can form intervals around them containing only one event each. The a priori probability for an interval of length $\mathrm dt$ to contain an event of type $X$ was $\lambda\mathrm dt$, and likewise $\mu\mathrm dt$ for type $Y$. Thus, the posterior probability, given that an event occurred in the interval, that it was of type $X$ is

$$
\frac{\lambda\mathrm dt}{\lambda\mathrm dt+{\mu\mathrm dt}}=\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\;.
$$

Since the probabilities for all intervals in a Poisson process are independent, and $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be independent, each event is an independent Bernoulli experiment with success probability $\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}$, so adding them yields a binomial variable with that success probability.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of conditional probability, we have for each positive integer $n$ and nonnegative integer $k\leqslant n$:
$$
\mathbb P(X=k\mid X+Y=n) = \frac{\mathbb P(X=k,X+Y=n)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=n)} = \frac{\mathbb P(X=k)\mathbb P(Y=n-k)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=n)}.
$$
Now,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X+Y=n) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb P(X+Y=n\mid X=k)\mathbb P(X=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb P(X=k)\mathbb P(Y=n-k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda ^k}{k!} e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=  \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\lambda^k \mu^{n-k}\\
&=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\lambda^k \mu^{n-k}\\
&=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{n!}(\lambda+\mu)^n, 
\end{align}
so that $X+Y$ has Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda+\mu$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb P(X=k)\mathbb P(Y=n-k)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=n)} &= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\frac{(\lambda+\mu)^n}{n!}}\\
&= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{\lambda^k \mu^{n-k}}{(\lambda+\mu)^k(\lambda+\mu)^{n-k}}\\
&= \binom nk\left(\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\right)^k\left(\frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{n-k},
\end{align}
and hence conditioned on $\{X+Y=n\}$, $X$ has $\mathrm{Bin}\left(n,\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\right)$ distribution.