# how to solve this Poisson distribution problem?

Tags: poisson-distribution

I got this Poisson distribution problem.

There's a clothes shop, and average number of customers per 1 hour are 5 men , 10 women, independent each other, in Poisson distribution.
If for 30 minutes there had been totally 10 customers, what's the probability of women customer more than 2?

- This is how I solved.
  Poisson average of man customers for 30 minute = m = 2.5

women = w = 5

all = a = 7.5

then the solution is 
p(w>2 | a=10)

=1- [ p(w>2 ∩ a=10)/p(a=10)]

= 1- { [p(w=0)*p(m=10) + p(w=1) * p(m=9)]/p(a=10)

(solve with Poisson formula)

=0.9996

I'm not quite sure if this is right,
because not sure if  `p(w=1 ∩ a=10)`  can be interpreted right into

```
p(w=1) * p(m=9)
```

.
Is this approach right? or am I missing something
Thank you verymuch

Comment: This approach is right. The event $\{w=1,a=10\}$ coincides with the event $\{w=1,m=9\}$ and the last is the intersection of two indpendent events.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is generally correct, but where you have $w\gt2$ the second time it should be $w\le2$ instead, and you're missing the $w=2$ case in the sum below that.

However, a somewhat simpler approach would be: Conditional on the total number of customers, each customer is independently a man with probability $\frac13$ and a woman with probability $\frac23$, so the probability for more than $2$ women is

$$
1-\sum_{w=0}^2\binom{10}w\left(\frac23\right)^w\left(\frac13\right)^{10-w}=\frac{19616}{19683}\approx0.9966\;.
$$

See [Finding expectation of a Poisson variable when condition has been made](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510671).